# Wamp + Pdo Mysql could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

recently i install the Wamp last version in my local computer. Before that i used php in Windows 7 - IIS 7.5. I used PDO mysql and it workd just fine.

```
try {
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=aaa;charset=utf8", "root", "root");
} catch ( PDOException $e ){
     print $e->getMessage();
}
```

But when i pass the iss to the wamp, Pdo_mysql not worked. When i visit my db page, it giving error 'could not find driver'. I searched in google but i cant figure this out.

Extensions

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
```

phpinfo()
[image: PDO says not installed driver :/]

Comment: @zerkms, check again! OP, have you restarted Apache after editing the config?

Comment: @meda Looks like I need glasses too!

Comment: @traBolics not an answer but you should ditch WAMP and use XAMPP. they both achieve the same tasks, however XAMPP offers much more features.

Comment: @meda I dont understand, it worked. But why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you get this error while you can still see it enabled in `php.ini` then `WAMP` is responsible for this issue.

I suggest you to use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are editing on php.ini in the apache servers bin folder `(e.g: \apache2.4.18\bin)` If you are editing the php.ini in your `php` folder those changes will not work. Please check your `php.ini` in your `apache\bin` to see if you have `extension=php_mysql.dll` and don't forget to restart the services.