# Php Pdo - Selecting last inserted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

i have a 'insert into' and 'select' querys together in one query.

```
$_SESSION['LoginUID']=1;
$Mesaj='ffdd';
$Ek=12;
$cid=112;
$Kaydet=$db->query("
               Insert Into Reply (Kimden,Mesaj,Ek,cid) 
               Values (".$_SESSION['LoginUID'].",'$Mesaj',$Ek,$cid);
               select r_id,KayitZaman from Reply 
               where r_id=LAST_INSERT_ID();")
            ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But i cant select last inserted row. It must return like this
<kbd>m_id</kbd>  <kbd>KayitZaman</kbd>       
<kbd>16</kbd>      <kbd>1413130807000</kbd>

How can i do that in one query? Or other way.

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the last inserted id via PDO (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057954/get-last-insert-id-after-a-prepared-insert-with-pdo))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run two queries at the same time, only one at the time

After the insert, run the select:

```
$stmt = $db->query('select r_id,KayitZaman from Reply where r_id=LAST_INSERT_ID()');
```

or you can use the built in function to pass the last inserted Id

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select r_id,KayitZaman from Reply where r_id= ?');
$stmt->execute(array($db->lastInsertId()));
```

If you want to do the whole thing at once then create a stored procedure.

---

**EDIT:**

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_get_reply(IN `p_Kimden`, 
                                      IN `p_Mesaj`, 
                                      IN `p_Ek`, 
                                      IN `p_cid`)
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `Reply` (`Kimden`, `Mesaj`, `Ek`, `cid`) 
   VALUES (p_Kimden, p_Mesaj, p_Ek, p_cid);

   SELECT `r_id`, `KayitZaman` 
   FROM Reply WHERE r_id=LAST_INSERT_ID()
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

then call the function from PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL sp_insert_get_reply(?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(($_SESSION['LoginUID'], $Mesaj, $Ek, $cid));
```

Comment: Can you give me an example procedure for insert and return?

Comment: @traBolics I expanded on my answer, I also answered an [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208509/wamp-pdo-mysql-could-not-find-driver/26331128#26331128)

Answer (score 0):

You should try issuing your `insert` in a PDO `exec()` call, and following it up with your `select` in the `query` call.  You can still use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your `select` query and retain data integrity.

If, for some reason, you *must* do the two statements in a single request from your program, you can use the multiple-statement feature of `mysqli` or you can write a stored procedure.